# selecting data with highest field value in a field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table, and I'd like to select rows with the highest value. For example:

```
----------------
| user | index |
----------------
|  1   |   1   |
|  2   |   1   |
|  2   |   2   |
|  3   |   4   |
|  3   |   7   |
|  4   |   1   |
|  5   |   1   |
----------------
```

Expected result:

```
----------------
| user | index |
----------------
|  1   |   1   |
|  2   |   2   |
|  3   |   7   |
|  4   |   1   |
|  5   |   1   |
----------------
```

How may I do so? I assume it can be done by some oracle function I am not aware of?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: BTW [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16292588/1369235) also works when you have [more than one columns](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a6ab/1) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have more than one column

```
select user , index
from (
  select u.* , row_number() over (partition by user order by index desc) as rnk
  from   some_table u)
where rnk = 1
```

- `user` is a reserved word - you should use a different name for the column.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `MAX()` function for that with grouping user column like this:

```
  SELECT "user"
        ,MAX("index") AS "index"
    FROM Table1
GROUP BY "user"
ORDER BY "user";
```

Result:

```
| USER | INDEX |
----------------
|    1 |     1 |
|    2 |     2 |
|    3 |     7 |
|    4 |     1 |
|    5 |     1 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c1aa/11)

Answer (score 1):

```
 select user,max(index) index from tbl 
 group by user;
```

Comment: Please don't add duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use analytic functions:

```
select user,index, max(index) over (partition by user order by 1 ) highest from YOURTABLE
```

**`Note:`** Try NOT to use words like user, index, date etc.. as your column names, as they are reserved words for Oracle. If you will use, then use them with quotation marks, eg. "index", "date"...